# Left join con rango de fechas y función de agregación

Tags: sql-server, select, join

Espero me puedan ayudar, tengo el siguiente esquema:

[image: Esquema BD]

Lo que he tratado de hacer es una consulta que me devuelva todos los productos tengan o no venta en un rango de fechas, agregando el rango en la cláusula on:

```
SELECT P.NOMBRE AS Producto, T.NOMBRE AS Tamaño, 
COUNT(DP.ID_PRODUCTO) AS Vendidos
FROM PRODUCTO AS P 
LEFT JOIN TAMANOS AS T ON(P.TAMANO = T.ID)
LEFT JOIN DETALLE_PEDIDO AS DP ON(P.CODIGO = DP.ID_PRODUCTO)
LEFT JOIN PEDIDO AS PE ON(PE.CODIGO = DP.COD_PEDIDO)
LEFT JOIN PAGO AS PA ON(PE.CODIGO = PA.COD_PEDIDO AND PA.FECHA BETWEEN '28/10/2018' AND '28/10/2018') 
GROUP BY P.NOMBRE, T.NOMBRE 
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

Obteniendo como resultado todos los productos vendidos desde el inicio, no considerando el rango de fechas:

[image: Obteniendo como resultado todos los productos vendidos desde el inicio, no considerando el rango de fechas:]

he probado agregando el rango de fechas en cláusula where:

```
SELECT P.NOMBRE AS Producto, T.NOMBRE AS Tamaño, 
COUNT(DP.ID_PRODUCTO) AS Vendidos
FROM PRODUCTO AS P 
LEFT JOIN TAMANOS AS T ON(P.TAMANO = T.ID)
LEFT JOIN DETALLE_PEDIDO AS DP ON(P.CODIGO = DP.ID_PRODUCTO)
LEFT JOIN PEDIDO AS PE ON(PE.CODIGO = DP.COD_PEDIDO)
LEFT JOIN PAGO AS PA ON(PE.CODIGO = PA.COD_PEDIDO) 
WHERE PA.FECHA BETWEEN '28/10/2018' AND '28/10/2018'
GROUP BY P.NOMBRE, T.NOMBRE 
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

y el resultado es solamente el producto vendido ese día:

[image: y el resultado es solamente el producto vendido ese día:]

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que la consulta me devuelva todos los productos existentes tengan o no venta en un rango de fechas?

Espero me haya explica bien, de antemano gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Si en lugar de LEFT JOINs utilizás un subquery?

Probá con algo así:

```
SELECT P.NOMBRE AS Producto
    ,T.NOMBRE AS Tamaño
    ,ISNULL((
      SELECT COUNT(1)
      FROM DETALLE_PEDIDO AS DP
      INNER JOIN PEDIDO AS PE ON PE.CODIGO = DP.COD_PEDIDO
      INNER JOIN PAGO AS PA ON PE.CODIGO = PA.COD_PEDIDO
      WHERE DP.ID_PRODUCTO = P.CODIGO
        AND PA.FECHA BETWEEN '28/10/2018' AND '28/10/2018'), 0) AS Vendidos
FROM PRODUCTO AS P
LEFT JOIN TAMANOS AS T ON (P.TAMANO = T.ID)
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

Espero te sirva.

¡Suerte!